# Access violation error_xutility

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, access-violation

I have problem with my program I don't know what to do...

```
#ifndef CUSTOMER_H
#define CUSTOMER_H 
#include <string>

class customer
{
public:
    customer(void);
        int getphoneNumber () const;
        void setAll_1( int, int, int, int, double, int);
        void setAll_2( std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string);

        void Display();
        ~customer(void);

private:
        int smartCardNumber;
        int serviceNumber;
        int billNumber;
        int phoneNumber;
        int customerID;
        int accountNumber;
        std::string firstName, lastName;
        std::string address;
        std::string password;
        double balance;

};

#endif // !CUSTOMER_H
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "customer.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

customer::customer(void)
{
    accountNumber =0;
}

customer::~customer(void)
{
}
int customer::getAccountNumber()
{
    return accountNumber;
}

void customer::setAll_1( int cusID, int smartCN, int serNum, int billNum,double balanc, int accountNum)
{
    customerID = cusID; smartCardNumber = smartCN; serviceNumber =serNum;
    billNumber = billNum; accountNumber = accountNum; balance = balanc;
}
void customer::setAll_2( string fS, string lS, string add, string pass)
{
    firstName = fS; lastName = lS;
    address = add; password = pass;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "customer.h"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int getAccount( const char * const prompt );

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    fstream inCustomer ("1.txt", ios::in | ios::out );
    if (!inCustomer)
        cerr << "file not opened";
    customer cus1;
    int accountNumber = getAccount( "Enter new account number" );
    inCustomer.seekg( ( accountNumber - 1 ) * sizeof( customer ) );
    inCustomer.read( reinterpret_cast< char * >( &cus1 ), sizeof( customer ) );                          
    if ( cus1.getAccountNumber() == 0 )
    {
        int smartCardNumber, serviceNumber, billNumber, phoneNumber;
        int customerID;
        string firstName, lastName, address, password;
        double balance = 10000;

        cout << setw( 20 ) <<" Customer ID: ";
        cin >> customerID;
        cout << setw( 20 ) << " Customer firstName & lastName : " << endl;
        cin >> firstName >> lastName ;
        cout << setw( 20 ) << " Customer address: " << endl;
        cin >>  address;
        cout << setw( 20 ) << " Customer Service Number" << endl ;
        cin >> serviceNumber;
        cout << setw( 20 ) << " Customer Smart Card Number: " <<endl;
        cin >> smartCardNumber;
        cout<< setw( 20 ) << " Customer Bill Number : " <<endl;
        cin >> billNumber;
        cout  << setw( 20 ) << " Customer Phone Number: " << endl ;
        cin >> phoneNumber;
        cus1.setAll_1(customerID, smartCardNumber, serviceNumber, billNumber, balance, accountNumber);
        cus1.setAll_2(firstName, lastName, address, password);
        inCustomer.seekp( ( accountNumber - 1 ) * sizeof( customer ) );                                     
        inCustomer.write( reinterpret_cast< const char * >( &cus1 ), sizeof( customer ) );         
    } 
    else 
        cout << "Account #" << accountNumber << " already contains information." << endl;

    return 0;
}
                        int getAccount( const char * const prompt )
                        {
                            int accountNumber;
                            do
                            {
                                cout << prompt << " (1 - 100): ";
                                cin >> accountNumber;
                            } while ( accountNumber < 1 || accountNumber > 100 );
                            return accountNumber;
                        }
```

when I run the code, returning of this function, it shows me this: !(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYn0l.png)![1]

so why is this happening and how to avoid this memory exception ? thanks

Comment: You can't save `std::string` objects like that. Search for "serialization".

Comment: You're opening a file as text but trying to use it as a binary file. That won't work because of line ending translation in Windows.  Another small piece of advice, don't use TCHAR, chances are you do not need it and it just makes your code non-portable.